# Keras: difference between test_on_batch and predict_on_batch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

In Philippe Remy's [blog post](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) on stateful LSTM, at the bottom he says "You may have to do your validation/testing manually by calling predict_on_batch() or test_on_batch()".

Looking at [the documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/), predict_on_batch does this:

```
predict_on_batch(self, x)

Returns predictions for a single batch of samples.

Arguments

    x: Input samples, as a Numpy array.

Returns

Numpy array(s) of predictions.
```

And test_on_batch does this:

```
test_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight=None)

Test the model on a single batch of samples.

Arguments

    x: Numpy array of test data, or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple inputs. If all inputs in the model are named, you can also pass a dictionary mapping input names to Numpy arrays.
    y: Numpy array of target data, or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple outputs. If all outputs in the model are named, you can also pass a dictionary mapping output names to Numpy arrays.
    sample_weight: Optional array of the same length as x, containing weights to apply to the model's loss for each sample. In the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples, sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().

Returns

Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics). The attribute model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for the scalar outputs
```

I'm using train_on_batch in my training loop, basically exactly as the blog post does. How do I know whether to use predict_on_batch or test_on_batch for cross-validation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So basically:

- `predict_on_batch` is providing you a set of predictions for data you feed as an argument. If you train a network for recognizing cats and dogs - once you feed an image to `predict_on_batch` method - you'll get probability if a given image has a cat or a dog in it. You can also use these probabilities to evaluate your model.
- `test_on_batch` is providing you a scalar(s) which measures how well is your model performing. Given images and true labels - it's computing a bunch of losses and metrics (defined at model compilation) which measure how your model fits the data.

The suffix `on_batch` comes from the fact that model is performing all computations at once. Sometimes it's not feasible so it's better to divide data in small chunks and perform multiple computations. `keras` provides you functions to do this automatically. So [`predict`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict) is equivalent to `predict_on_batch` and [`evaluate`](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate) - to `test_on_batch`.

In order to choose function used during cross-validation - you need to use:

- `predict` / `predict_on_batch` when you need the actual predictions, not only metrics values. In this case, however, you still need to compute metrics values.
- `test_on_batch` / `evaluate` when you simply need metrics values.

So - as you may see - you can actually combine these two functions while evaluating your model. If you simply want metrics - try `test_on_batch` / `evaluate` as it may save you a lot of computations.

Comment: So does that mean that for cross-validation, I should use test_on_batch because it returns the metrics?